# What is wrong with my search for money code in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I need help fixing my code

```
@client.command
@commands.cooldown(5, 20, commands.BucketType.user)
async def search(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    peen = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    tu = random.randint(19, 157)
    rand = random.choice(hs)
    embed54=discord.Embed(title='Search in...', description=f'{rand}, {rand}, {rand}')
    embed54.add_footer('Do !beg for money as well!')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed54)

    await client.wait_for(rand)
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channnel == ctx.channel
        embed53=discord.Embed(title='You Found...', description=f'${tu} From {ctx.message}')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed53)
        fa = tu
        peen += fa
```

why does it not work
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
i need help
pls it gives error every time so help me
also yeah boi

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You have set an `await` outside of a function. You would also have to explain to me why you wait for `rand` and where you defined `hs`? `wait_for` waits for a user input.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what `hs` means or how you defined it I omitted the whole thing once and replaced it with a simple number just for my test.

**To clarify beforehand:** You had errors in creating an embed, in your `check` function and in your way of rendering with `await` functions and some typos.

***This method works fine for me:***

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(5, 20, commands.BucketType.user)
async def search(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel # New check

    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    hs = # DEFINE WHAT IT IS! <<<

    peen = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    tu = random.randint(19, 157)
    rand = random.choice(hs)
    embed54 = discord.Embed(title='Search in...', description=f'{rand}, {rand}, {rand}')
    embed54.set_footer(text='Do !beg for money as well!') # SET footer

    await ctx.send(embed=embed54)

    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) # Wait for MESSAGE, add check
    if response.content == rand: # I assume you want to get the author say one of the numbers
        embed53 = discord.Embed(title='You Found...', description=f'${tu} From {ctx.message.content}')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed53)
        fa = tu
        peen += fa
    else: # If the number is not in the embed
        await ctx.send("You did not respond correctly.")
```

**What did we do?**

- Re-built your check as it is `m.channel` and **NOT** `m.channnel`, just a little typo here
- Added a "real" footer, as `embed54.add_footer` does not exist, it is `embed54.set_footer(text='', icon_url='')`
- `wait_for` a `'message'` from the author of the message and if `rand`, which you have to define as I do not know what `hs` is, is not in his answer he will not get whatever you defined. (`if`/`else` statements)
- Replaced `ctx.message` with `ctx.message.content` as otherwise it will give out a [longer "text"](http://prntscr.com/116e6sm) than just [`search`](http://prntscr.com/116e7gw)

**!** *Since there were many mistakes in your code I would recommend to have a closer look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)* again **!**

Comment: it says there is no module check when i import it?

Comment: You need to "import"/add the `check` function we defined, I already did that for you...

Comment: If it helped you, please accept it as an answer to your question. There is no need from your side to provide the full code as an answer again. :)

Answer (score 0):

i actually did this and it worked:

@commands.cooldown(5, 20, commands.BucketType.user)
async def search(ctx):
def check(m):
return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel # New check

```
await open_account(ctx.author)
user = ctx.author
users = await get_bank_data()

peen = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
tu = random.randint(19, 157)
rand = random.choice(hs)
rand1 = random.choice(hs)
rand2 = random.choice(hs)
embed54 = discord.Embed(title='Search in...', description=f'{rand}, {rand1}, {rand2}')
embed54.set_footer(text='Do !beg for money as well!') # SET footer

await ctx.send(embed=embed54)

response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) # Wait for MESSAGE, import check
if response.content == rand: # I assume you want to get the author say one of the numbers
    embed53 = discord.Embed(title='You Found...', description=f'${tu} From {ctx.message.content}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed53)
    earnings = tu
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)
      return True
else:
  response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  if response.content == rand1: # I assume you want to get the author say one of the numbers
      embed53 = discord.Embed(title='You Found...', description=f'${tu} From {ctx.message.content}')
      await ctx.send(embed=embed53)
      earnings = tu
      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
      with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
        return True
  else:
      response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) # Wait for MESSAGE, import check
      if response.content == rand1: # I assume you want to get the author say one of the numbers
          embed53 = discord.Embed(title='You Found...', description=f'${tu} From {ctx.message.content}')
          await ctx.send(embed=embed53)
          earnings = tu
          users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
      
      
          with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(users,f)
            return True
```